# POST Request failed with status code 500 at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd Express.js

Tags: javascript, express

I am creating a HTTP request for a CRUD application through JS. The objective of this request is to simply create a record in the Logins database of a new user account. When  I try to request this, I get a 500 error:

I make the request in a silly little test script:

```js
const axios = require("axios");

var http = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/",
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
    }
});

class UserDataService {
    getAll(){
        return http.get("/users");
    }

    get(id){
        return http.get(`/users/${id}`);
    }

    create(data){
        return http.post("/users", data);
    }

    update(id, data){
        return http.put(`/users/${id}`, data);
    }

    delete(id){
        return http.delete(`/users/${id}`);
    }

    findByUsername(username){
        return http.get(`/users?username=${username}`);
    }

    authenticateLogin(data){
        console.log(data);
        return http.get("/login");
    }
}

function main(){
    const uds = new UserDataService();
    // http://localhost:8080'/api/users
    uds.create({
        username: "root",
        email: "root@enron.com",
        password: "password"
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

main();
```

This gets routed into `users.routes.js`:

```js
router.post("/users", users.create);
```

Which then gets sent to `users.controller.js`:

```js
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    console.log("User being created");
    const user = {
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: crypto.createHash("md5").update(req.body.password).digest("hex")
    };
    Users.create(user)
        .then(data => {
            res.send(data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message || "Error occurred when creating a user"
            })
        });
};
```

This is my error:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (/home/amicharski/WebstormProjects/profrec/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/home/amicharski/WebstormProjects/profrec/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/home/amicharski/WebstormProjects/profrec/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:293:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
```

Comment: Seems like a server error, do you see anything at the backend?

Comment: All I see is the error I posted

Comment: try using postman to see if the backend is working or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how this worked, but I put quotes around the username, email, and password field names when I called the API:

```js
function main(){
    const uds = new UserDataService();
    // http://localhost:8080'/api/users
    uds.create({
        "username": "root",
        "email": "root@enron.com",
        "password": "password"
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

main();
```